# Packer file provisioner doesn't copy

Tags: amazon-web-services, build, devops, provisioning, packer

I have a File Provisioner configured on my packer template json:

```
"provisioners": [{
        "type": "file",
        "source": "packer/api-clients/database.yml",
        "destination": "/tmp/api-clients-database.yml"
    },
```

The code below doesn't work when I'm trying to build an AMI on Amazon AWS, it always says:

```
Bad source 'packer/api-clients/database.yml': stat packer/api-clients/database.yml: no such file or directory
```

If I do this:

```
"source": "api-clients/database.yml",
```

It works like a charm. But I must have all my Packer files inside of a packer folder within my app folder for organization purposes.

What am I doing wrong?

My app folder is like this:

```
api_v1
├── template.json
├── app
│   ├── bin
│   ├── config
│   ├── packer
│   │   ├── api-clients
│   │   │   └── database.yml
│   ├── lib
│   ├── log
│   ├── ...
```

It seems that it has something to do with Relative Paths / Absolute Paths on Packer but I couldn't figure out what is wrong...

Thanks in advance,

Comment: In which directory are you executing the packer build command?

Answer (score 1):

Since the path doesn't start with a `/` it's a relative path. The are relative to the current working directory when executing `packer build`.

With source `packer/api-clients/database.yml` you have to run packer from the `app` directory, i.e.

```
packer build ../template.json
```

With source `api-clients/database.yml` you have to run packer from the `packer` directory, i.e.

```
packer build ../../template.json
```

For more info see [Packer documentation - File provisioner: source](https://www.packer.io/docs/provisioners/file.html#source).

Answer (score 0):

It is as you have surmised a path thing.

You do not say from what folder you are calling packer and what the calling command is, or when you have it working with "source": "api-clients/database.yml", if you have moved the api-clients folder or it works with packer in that location.

If your folder structure will always look that way then to avoid confusions if you use a full path for the source it will always work no matter where you run packer from

eg
     /api_v1/app/packer/api-clients/database.yml

if you must use relative paths then make sure that the source path is always relative from the folder in which packer is run.